# Variable indefinida al insertar en una base de datos

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código que inserta información de alumnos en mi base de datos:

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidop = $_POST["apellidop"]; //creamos busquedacarrera para darle un nombre unico a la  busqueda de ese mismo
$apellidom = $_POST["apellidom"];//al igual que con la de semestre
$nocontrol = $_POST["nocontrol"];
$carrera = $_POST["carrera"];
$semestre = $_POST["semestre"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];
//Esto lo ponemos para que se enlaze con el html de mi documento buscar
//hacemos una instancia
try{
$base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root','');
$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$resultado->execute(array(":nom"=>$nombre,":apep"=>$apellidop,":apem"=>$apellidom,":noconl"=>$nocontrol,":carrera"=>$carrera,":semestre"=>$semestre,":contra"=>$contrasena));

$sql="INSERT INTO altas(nombre,apep,apem,nocontrol,carrera,semestre,contrasena)
VALUES(:nom,:apep,:apem,:noconl,:carrera,:semestre,:contra)";

//mediante marcadores vamos a realizar la consultas como es el caso de carre y seme , si el alumno cumple con estas dos se me imprimira
$resultado = $base->prepare($sql); //codigo para evitar la inyeccion sql
//lo que pongamos en execute es lo que nos aparecera en la consulta todo lo relacion en este caso a ige
if($ultimo = true){
echo"Registro Exitoso";
}else{
echo"Registro no insertado";
$ultimo->closeCursor();}
}catch(Excepcion $e){
    die('Error:' . $e->GetMessage());
    }finally{
      $base = null;  
    }
    ?> 
    <?php
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto, recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: resultado in , Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on null in

¿A qué se debe ese error? ¿Qué debo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Buenas Noches tengo varias horas y no logro saber porque tengo estos errores:/

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español, te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio para ver como funcionamos, al igual que pasar por [ask] para ver como elaborar una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta añadiendo una explicación sobre lo que estás tratando de hacer y sobre cual es el problema que tienes para que así sea más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estas ejecutando resultado antes de decirle que quieres que ejecute. Prueba a cambiar el orden de:

```
$resultado->execute(array(":nom"=>$nombre,":apep"=>$apellidop,":apem"=>$apellidom,":noconl"=>$nocontrol,":carrera"=>$carrera,":semestre"=>$semestre,":contra"=>$contrasena));

$sql="INSERT INTO altas(nombre,apep,apem,nocontrol,carrera,semestre,contrasena)
VALUES(:nom,:apep,:apem,:noconl,:carrera,:semestre,:contra)";

//mediante marcadores vamos a realizar la consultas como es el caso de carre y seme , si el alumno cumple con estas dos se me imprimira
$resultado = $base->prepare($sql); //codigo para evitar la inyeccion sql
```

por:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO altas(nombre,apep,apem,nocontrol,carrera,semestre,contrasena)
VALUES(:nom,:apep,:apem,:noconl,:carrera,:semestre,:contra)";

//mediante marcadores vamos a realizar la consultas como es el caso de carre y seme , si el alumno cumple con estas dos se me imprimira
$resultado = $base->prepare($sql); //codigo para evitar la inyeccion sql

$resultado->execute(array(":nom"=>$nombre,":apep"=>$apellidop,":apem"=>$apellidom,":noconl"=>$nocontrol,":carrera"=>$carrera,":semestre"=>$semestre,":contra"=>$contrasena));
```